# Lavalink/Discord.py Player doesn't play any music

Tags: python, discord.py

I've updated my discord bot from discord.py 1.5.0 to 2.1.0 and I am currently having issues with it not playing any music. It connects just fine and Lavalink processes the play-request, but no music is hearable. I use the standard play function given in the [Lavalink.py wrapper](https://github.com/Devoxin/Lavalink.py/blob/master/examples/music.py).

```
class MusicCog(commands.Cog):
def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot
    self.bot.music = lavalink.Client("YOUR_CLIENT_ID")


    self.bot.music.add_node('localhost', 7000, 'youshallnotpass', 'eu', 'music-node')

@commands.command(aliases=["j"])
async def join(self, ctx):
    print('Joined a Channel')
    member = utils.find(lambda m: m.id == ctx.author.id, ctx.guild.members)
    if member is not None and member.voice is not None:
        vc = member.voice.channel
        player = self.bot.music.player_manager.create(ctx.guild.id)
        if not player.is_connected:
            player.store('channel', ctx.channel.id)
            player.store('guild', ctx.guild)

            await vc.guild.change_voice_state(channel=vc)
    else:
        await ctx.send("You have to be in a Voicechannel to do that!")
        raise Exception(f"{member} was not in a Voicechannel at the time")

@commands.command(aliases=["pl", "p"])
async def play(self, ctx, *, query):
    #await self.join(ctx)
    await asyncio.sleep(.5)
    player = self.bot.music.player_manager.create(ctx.guild.id)

    if not url_rx.match(query):
        query = f"ytsearch:{query}"

    results = await player.node.get_tracks(query)
    tracks = results["tracks"]
    print(results)
    if results["loadType"] == "PLAYLIST_LOADED":
        i = 0
        for track in tracks:
            i += 1
            player.add(requester=ctx.author.id, track=track)
        await ctx.send(f"Enqueued Playlist with {i} songs!")
    else:
        track = tracks[0]
        await ctx.send(f" Enqueued {track['info']['title']}")
        player.add(requester=ctx.author.id, track=track)

    if not player.is_playing:
        await player.play()

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(MusicCog(bot))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I've finally fixed the problem, here is the reason why it didn't work (from the known issues on the Lavalink.py Github)

> discord.py removed the socket_response event which is what
> lavalink.py requires to forward voice updates to the server

Implementing the new example.py from the github page fixed the problem.